# What is the main meaning of "relieve you of your command"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It's a line of [The Big Bang Theroy](http://www.kekenet.com/video/201612/482272.shtml)

> Pursuant to starfleet general order 104 section a, You are deemed
>   unfit and I hereby **relieve you of your command**.

The main meaning is "relieve you" or "relieve your command"?

What is "you of your command"?

Answer (score 2):

To relieve someone of something is to release them from their duty.

In that context, command can refer to a position of highest (military authority).

So it means the person is fired from his job/position.

Comment: Yes, it is a euphemism. A lowly private might be kicked out of the Army by receiving a dishonourable discharge. A lofty general would be 'relieved of his command' - either sacked or reduced to the ranks. In general, people from  wealthy and influential backgrounds tend to reach high office in the forces.  Powerful families don't like words like "fired" or "sacked" being used about their relatives. A similar euphemism in everyday life is "let go". *"John is unemployed now - he was let go by his boss last week."* It sounds better than "fired" but the long term effects are just the same.